# Remove tkinter widget called using .place

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I am working on an app using Tkinter and I have a small question.
For example, I have a label placed like this:

```
Label = Label(root, text="Hello").place(x=5, y=5)
```

Is there any way to hide the label when a button is pressed or when a function is called?

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should simply never chain `.place()` or any other geometry manager to the widget creator. It returns `None`.

```
lbl_name = Label(root, text="Hello")
lbl_name.place(x=5, y=5)
```

Now you can handle `lbl_name` as a label object. To hide it you can use:

```
lbl_name.place_forget()
```

Unfortunately, now its gone. Therefore, first save the place properties:

```
lbl_name = Label(root, text="Hello")
lbl_name.place(x=5, y=5)
lbl_name.saved = lbl_name.place_info()
```

You can now show it again with:

```
lbl_name.place(lbl_name.saved)
```

***Note***: You can print `lbl_name.saved`. It is a dictionary with all place-properties of the `lbl_name` Label object.